# Trying to get Google Sheets logs

Tags: logging, google-sheets, revision-history

Trying to get Google Sheets activity logs

I need to get google sheet logs showing the activities happening, so that

1. I can have a record of the changes done, on my computer.
2. I don't have to download the sheets every time and rather I can perform the recent changes from the logs.

So far the forums say that there is no way if anyone knows a way to get like logs preferably something looking like
"move column A to column D" etc. that would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets does not have a log.

The activity can be seen in History which you can access by pressing:
 <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd>

there you can track dow all changes to your spreadsheet based on the time and date.

[image: 0]

if you are interested in changes over time of specific cell, there is a relatively new feature by right-clicking the cell and selecting **Show edit history**

[image: 0]